# Wordpress custom query and sticky post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the posts of the current month keeping the sticky post on the top.

This is my code:

```
$today = getdate();

$args = array( 
    'monthnum' => $today["mon"], 
    'year' => $today["year"]
);

query_posts( $args );

while (have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // some code...

endwhile;
```

The result is a list of the posts in chronological order without holding the sticky post on the top.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You'd need a separate lookup and the `query_posts` arguments would be whatever is used to load the sticky.

Comment: @Epodax I want a list of posts with the sticky post in top. My code returns the chronological list of posts.

Comment: @JamieBicknell Can I obtain the desired result with a single loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my chip in on this, I haven't tested as I'm at work but let me know if you have any problems and I'll test and fix when I get home.

```
<?php
/*--- Create a sticky loop ---*/

$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

// These args will return only one sticky post
$stickyArgs = array(
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    // remove these to return all sticky posts
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

// create your query
$stickyQuery = new WP_Query( $stickyArgs );

    if ( isset($sticky[0]) ) {
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    }


wp_reset_query();

// I haven't comented this section because it was your code
$today = getdate();

$todayArgs = array( 
  'monthnum' => $today["mon"], 
  'year' => $today["year"]
);

$todayQuery = new WP_Query( $todayArgs );

    if ($todayQuery->have_posts()) {
        while($todayQuery->have_posts()) {
            $todayQuery->the_post();
                //
                // Post Content here
                //
        } // end while
    } // end if

// reset the query again.. this is optional, I don't know what else is on your page.
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: As I was afraid you can't manage all with a single loop.

Your code works correctly but if there are no sticky posts, shows the first post available.

To avoid this I changed the if condition: if ( isset( $sticky[0] ) ).

Many thanks :)

Comment: Hi @LucasPuerari

`if ( isset( $sticky[0] ) )` is a much better way, good shout (plus it actually works), glad I was able to help, I'll update my answer to reflect your suggestion :)